# Argument of \@sect has an extra }. \protect does not work

Tags: errors

I have a problem using a command "\greek" in section.

Here is an example of using the command \greek in normal text, which works fine.

```
\documentclass[polutonikogreek, oneside,11pt]{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\newcommand{\greek}[1]{{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}#1}}

\begin{document}
%\section{\protect\greek{Πρωταγόρας}}
    Protagoras (\greek{Πρωταγόρας}) says that 
    ``Man is the measure of all things'' (\greek{Ἄνθρωπος μέτρον}), 
    meaning that there is no objective truth. 
    One opinion can be better than another, 
    but it cannot be \emph{truer}.
\end{document}
```

However, if I try to use the command \greek in section, errors show. The message says "Argument of \@sect has an extra }. \section{\protect\greek{Πρωταγόρας}}".

Uncomment the line "%\section{\protect\greek{Πρωταγόρας}}" for example.
I have tried to use \protect, but it didn't help.

Any idea please?

Below is the source code of the class file "CUEDthesisPSnPDF" (I think it might be something to do with it).

```
%
% CUEDthesis v1.0
% By Harish Bhanderi <harish.bhanderi@cantab.net
% Version 1.0 released 15/07/2002
%-------------------------- identification ---------------------
%\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}[2003/01/11 v1.2 CUED thesis class]
%-------------------------- initial code -----------------------

%If you want to use a Report style document then uncomment the following 3 lines and comment the below 8 book style lines:
%\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{report}}
%\ProcessOptions\relax
%%\LoadClass[a4paper]{report}
%\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
%   \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{report}
%\else
%   \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{report}
%\fi
%%Bibliography
%%uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references for Report document class
%\renewcommand{\refname}{References}

%If you want to use a Book style document then uncomment the following 3 lines and comment the above 8 report style lines:
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
   \LoadClass[dvips, a4paper]{book}
\else
   \LoadClass[pdftex, a4paper]{book}
\fi

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers, authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{ifpdf}


%Bibliography
%uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references for Book document class
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
% note that this doesn't do much if you later define another bibliography style


% Nomenclature
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makeglossary
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
   \item[\textbf{Roman Symbols}]}{%             R - Roman
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
     \item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{%             G - Greek
      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{Z}}{%
        \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{%              Z- Superscripts
          \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
           \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%             S - Subscripts
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{X}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Other Symbols}]}{%    X - Other Symbols
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Terminology}]}{%    T - Terminology
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{%
         \item[\textbf{Abbreviations and Acronyms}]}%              A - Acronyms
                        {{}}}}}}}}}

\ifpdf
%-->
%--> Google.com search "hyperref options"
%-->
%--> http://www.ai.mit.edu/lab/sysadmin/latex/documentation/latex/hyperref/manual.pdf
%--> http://www.chemie.unibas.ch/~vogtp/LaTeX2PDFLaTeX.pdf
%--> http://www.uni-giessen.de/partosch/eurotex99/ oberdiek/print/sli4a4col.pdf
%--> http://me.in-berlin.de/~miwie/tex-refs/html/latex-packages.html
%-->
    \usepackage[ pdftex, plainpages = false, pdfpagelabels,
                 pdfpagelayout = useoutlines,
                 bookmarks,
                 bookmarksopen = true,
                 bookmarksnumbered = true,
                 breaklinks = true,
                 linktocpage,
                 pagebackref,
                 colorlinks = true,
                 linkcolor = blue,
                 urlcolor  = blue,
                 citecolor = red,
                 anchorcolor = green,
                 hyperindex = true,
                 hyperfigures
                 ]{hyperref}

    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png, .jpg, .pdf}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \pdfcompresslevel=9
    \graphicspath{{ThesisFigs/PNG/}{ThesisFigs/PDF/}{ThesisFigs/}}
\else
    \usepackage[ dvips,
                 bookmarks,
                 bookmarksopen = true,
                 bookmarksnumbered = true,
                 breaklinks = true,
                 linktocpage,
                 pagebackref,
                 colorlinks = true,
                 linkcolor = blue,
                 urlcolor  = blue,
                 citecolor = red,
                 anchorcolor = green,
                 hyperindex = true,
                 hyperfigures
                 ]{hyperref}

    \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps, .ps}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{ThesisFigs/EPS/}{ThesisFigs/}}
\fi

%define the page size including an offset for binding
%\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
%\setlength{\textheight}{700pt}
%\setlength{\textwidth}{500pt}


%A4 settings
\ifpdf
   \pdfpageheight=297mm
   \pdfpagewidth=210mm
\else
   \setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
   \setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\fi

\setlength{\hoffset}{0.00cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.00cm}

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1.96cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.54cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.36cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.00cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20.84cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{2.36cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\newcommand{\submittedtext}{{Dissertation presented for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Faculty of Theology at Stellenbosch University}}
%
%
% DECLARATIONS
%
% These macros are used to declare arguments needed for the
% construction of the title page and other preamble.

% The year and term the degree will be officially conferred
\def\degreedate#1{\gdef\@degreedate{#1}}
% The full (unabbreviated) name of the degree
\def\degree#1{\gdef\@degree{#1}}
% The name of your college or department(eg. Trinity, Pembroke, Maths, Physics)
\def\collegeordept#1{\gdef\@collegeordept{#1}}
% The name of your University
\def\university#1{\gdef\@university{#1}}
% Defining the crest
\def\crest#1{\gdef\@crest{#1}}
% Defining the Promotor
\def\promotor#1{\gdef\@promotor{#1}}

% These macros define an environment for front matter that is always
% single column even in a double-column document.

\newenvironment{alwayssingle}{%
       \@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
       \else\newpage\fi}
       {\if@restonecol\twocolumn\else\newpage\fi}

%define title page layout
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
\begin{alwayssingle}
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\relax}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
%  \null\vfill
  \begin{center}
    { \Large {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
{\large \vspace*{20mm} {{\@crest} \par} \vspace*{20mm}}
    {{\Large \@author} \par}
{\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@collegeordept} \par}

\vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@university} \par}

\vspace*{10mm}
    {{\@promotor} \par}

\vspace*{20mm}
    {{\submittedtext} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {\it {\@degree} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}
  \null\vfill
\end{alwayssingle}}

% declaration
%
% The declaration environment makes sure the declaration gets its
% own page and is set out in verse format.

\newenvironment{declaration}
{\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{alwayssingle}
%\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Declaration}
%\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}


\newenvironment{ecsa}
{\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{alwayssingle}
%\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries{ECSA Exit Level Outcomes Reference}}
%\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

% ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
%
% The acknowledgements environment puts a large, bold, centered
% "Acknowledgements" label at the top of the page. The acknowledgements
% themselves appear in a quote environment, i.e. tabbed in at both sides, and
% on its own page.

\newenvironment{acknowledgements}
{\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{alwayssingle}
%\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
%\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

% The acknowledgementslong environment puts a large, bold, centered
% "Acknowledgements" label at the top of the page. The acknowledgement itself
% does not appears in a quote environment so you can get more in.

\newenvironment{acknowledgementslong}
{\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{alwayssingle}\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bfseries Acknowledgements}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%ABSTRACT
%
%The abstract environment puts a large, bold, centered "Abstract" label at
%the top of the page. The abstract itself appears in a quote environment,
%i.e. tabbed in at both sides, and on its own page.

\newenvironment{abstracts} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{plain}
%  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
%  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

\newenvironment{opsomming} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{plain}
%  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Opsomming}
%  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%The abstractlong environment puts a large, bold, centered "Abstract" label at
%the top of the page. The abstract itself does not appears in a quote
%environment so you can get more in.

\newenvironment{abstractslong} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{plain}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm} \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}

%The abstractseparate environment is for running of a page with the abstract
%on including title and author etc as required to be handed in separately

\newenvironment{abstractseparate} {\begin{alwayssingle} \pagestyle{empty}
  \vspace*{-1in}
 \begin{center}
    { \Large {\bfseries {\@title}} \par}
    {{\large \vspace*{1ex} \@author} \par}
    {{\@promotor} \par}
{\large \vspace*{1ex}
    {{\@collegeordept} \par}
    {{\@university} \par}
\vspace*{1ex}
    {{\it \submittedtext} \par}
    {\it {\@degree} \par}
\vspace*{2ex}
    {\@degreedate}}
  \end{center}}
{\end{alwayssingle}}

%ROMANPAGES
%
% The romanpages environment set the page numbering to lowercase roman one
% for the contents and figures lists. It also resets
% page-numbering for the remainder of the dissertation (arabic, starting at 1).

\newenvironment{romanpages}
{\setcounter{page}{1}
  \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}}
{\newpage\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}\setcounter{page}{1}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where can we find this class `CUE....`?

Comment: Don't use `utf8x`, but `utf8`; and do `\DeclareRobustCommand{\greek}[1]{\foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with a fairly recent TeX distribution:

```
\documentclass[polutonikogreek,oneside,11pt]{CUEDthesisPSnPDF}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\greek}[1]{%
  \foreignlanguage{polutonikogreek}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{\greek{Πρωταγόρας}}

Protagoras (\greek{Πρωταγόρας}) says that
`Man is the measure of all things'' (\greek{Ἄνθρωπος μέτρον}),
 meaning that there is no objective truth.
One opinion can be better than another,
but it cannot be \emph{truer}.

\end{document}
```

Avoid `utf8x`.

[image]